# Debugging a legacy R script with very few functions

Tags: r, debugging

I am aware that R has certain functions such as `browser()`, `cat()`, and `print()` which can be used for basic debugging, and some R environments may have modern debuggers.

I am looking at a legacy script in an old environment which does not allow installation of a new, modern visual debugger.

I would have thought that `debug()` would be useful, but in fact it seems that the main functionality of the script uses very few functions;  it has many if-then expressions.

Thus my only obvious approach to debugging is to use `print()` and `cat()` to trace control flow and variable values.

Am I missing some obvious debugging tactic?

Thanks.

Comment: If I had a script with many (possibly nested) `if` expressions I might grab a pencil and a sheet of paper and draw a tree with all possible outcomes. I would then think about a way to avoid at least some of them and simplify the script.

Comment: I would just run the script in interactive mode, inserting`browser()` inside functions as I go along. It's 1980 all over again (I'm told).

Comment: I've been using browser() and print() - much like Roman said, it's the same debugging style we had around 1980, before GUI was widely available.